# Same code, different behaviors with different .NET framework versions

Tags: c#, .net

This code exhibits different behaviors with .NET v4.0 and v3.5 :

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("it-IT");
var tm = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00");
Console.WriteLine(tm);
```

Result in v3.5

```
2016-05-25T00.00.00   // using a .
```

Result in v4.0

```
2016-05-25T00:00:00   // using a :
```

I cannot find any KB or breaking changes related, and i would like to know if anyone have any hints about this?

NB: `DateTime.ParseExact` is also impacted.

Comment: what is the difference in your example?

Comment: I've seen this day similar behavior with croation culture

Comment: @techspider I assume the separator used in the time

Comment: Looks like v4 *fixed* this issue. [Italy use colons in times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_Italy)

Comment: Ok, didn't find this answers, sorry for the noise :-).

And `DateTime.ParseExact` throw in v3.5 and not in v4.0... it seems that a lot things changes under the hood...